# How to handle multiple delimiters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to read in `.csv` files that can have different delimiters. At the moment I am using `readtable` but that only handles one type and the use of `textscan` isn't really viable as the file contains 50+ columns.

The main two types of delimiter are `';'` and `','`. I am also using `uigetfile` in order for the user to select the file.

So I am wondering how I would go about handling more than one type of delimiter? The delimiter is consistent throughout each file and they all contain the same number of columns (hence my use of `readtable`).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could write your own interpreter using [regexp](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

Comment: Why isn't textscan viable for 50+ columns? I use it fine for multi-column input and it will handle multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to unify delimiters. Eg. replace all semicolons with commas or vice versa, like that

```
file = 'bad_delimiters.csv';
fd = fopen(file);
text = fscanf(fd,'%c');
semicolons = strfind(text,';');
text(semicolons) = ',';
fd = fopen('good_delimiters.csv', 'w');
fwrite(fd, text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have MATLAB version R2016b or later you can specify multiple delimiters for [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) by defining a set of [import options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#inputarg_opts), as illustrated in [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#bvghccx). You will first create a [`detectImportOptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delimitedtextimportoptions-object.html) object, change the [`'Delimiter'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delimitedtextimportoptions-object.html#property_d0e471690) to a cell array of characters, then pass these options to `readtable`:

```
opts = detectImportOptions('your_file.csv');
opts.Delimiter = {';', ','};
T = readtable('your_file.csv', opts);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently using 2015b so I can't use `detectImportOptions` :(.